# Can app be rejected if the user needs to log in?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Quoting from the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> 17.2 Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected.

My app let the user logs in via email and password (so far it'd get rejected), but it also provides one-click login with Facebook. If the user logs in with Facebook, he is able to deactivate the `email` permission thus letting him in without providing an email address at all. Is this acceptable as per App Store point of view?

The reason I'm asking is because App Store Review Guidelines are very subjective. It doesn't specifically says this way I described could get rejected, but I wouldn't be surprised if they did.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Quite a few apps have login & password before using them. They are available in the app store. e.g. Pandora. So it is possible to do it. But then again Apple Gods are very subjective. If one app passes doesn't mean that yours will too. Maybe you can add a "guest" link that requires no login / password with limited functionality and prompt the user its in their best interest to register / login first.

Comment: I think it means that the user should not be forced to use it. So like that nothing will work if the user does not log in. Guess if you let some features of the app work w/o log in that won't be a problem.

Comment: Will it pass if instead of 'email' I go for 'username' (since it isn't personal information) or should I go with no-login-at-all since it's safer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of approved apps that require login, a few even require the phone number to login (with SMS confirmation messages, and similar).

But Apple may ask you to justify your choice (why do you need the user's email/phone number?). If you don't have a good answer for that, using a username instead of email may be safer.

Of course as you said, the criteria are subjective. You may need to exchange some messages with them, and in worst case scenario change the process a bit to satisfy their requests.

EDIT - about the last comment: if you can keep all the app's functionality without a login, it's better to drop it - it will even make the user experience simpler. But if you actually need the login for your features, Apple will probably let you do it. Depending on the app, you could even have a "visiter mode" where the user can enter and use some of the features without signing up.